# How to understand this "I not only" structure

Tags: grammar

I read this sentence from a book.

*"I **not** only lost all my money - I also lost my passport".*

Why it's not "I am not only.." or "I don't only..".
I don't know how to describe this kind of grammar, couldn't get much help from google.
Could you please explain this to me? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question.

The answer, I think, is that *not only* acts as a unit. I can't think of another adverb which can take *not* in this way.*

The regular form *I didn't only lose all my money* is also possible.

*Constructions with *not* + adverb are common when there is no verb, as in "Do you always go that way?" "Not always"; or "He finished the job, but not quickly". But when there is a verb, the negative normally goes to the verb in the usually way "I don't always go that way"; "He didn't finish quickly".

**Edit:** I have thought of one more example: *not infrequently*. But neither *often* nor *frequently* works this way.

Comment: What about "not much"?

Comment: @EditingFrank: can you give an example of _not much [verb]_, as opposed to _don't much [verb]_? As I said, several adverbs are used this way when there isn't a verb.

Answer (score 1):

The fullest version of this coordinate pair is *not only . . . but also.* A slightly more economical version of the sentence would be “I lost *not only* all my money *but also* my passport”—since subject and verb remain the same, one can economize here by zeugma.

Answer (score 0):

It's a logical negation. Removing *not*, we get *I only lost all my money - I also lost my passport*, which is not correct; Adding the *also* invalidates the *only*. So, adding the *not* makes the sentence acceptable.

In common usage, this structure is used to reinforce the positive or negative aspect of the situation, as in *not only did one bad thing happen, but another did, so it's even worse* as opposed to *two bad things happened*.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about the anomalous **syntax** of _not_ in this construction.

Comment: @ColinFine It's a logical negation of *only*... there's nothing anomalous about this construct. As well, the question isn't about that, it's about explaining what's going on.

Comment: There are very few adverbs which allow this construction. I have thought of only one other: _not infrequently_. But you can't say _*I not merely went there_ or _*I not happily did it_. That makes it anomalous.

Comment: @ColinFine It works with *just* and *quite*, too, off the top of my head. Perhaps there is some constraint where it only works with quantitative adverbs? I want to say monosyllabic as well, but *only* defies that.

Comment: those don't work for me. Without a verb they're OK (_not quite_, _not just_) but with a verb the negative goes to the verb (_*I not just did it_; _*I not quite managed it_). Are those examples grammatical for you?

Comment: @ColinFine *Just*, in this scenario, works when used with the meaning of *only*, and requires a subordinate clause. *I not quite understand **[x]*** is something I hear not too infrequently, but I suppose it could be a bastardization of *I do not quite understand*.